# How to test if variables exists in function

Tags: php, phpunit

I have to take unit test this function

```
public function levels($id){
    switch($id){
        case 5: 
            $bread = 'N2';
        break;
        case 1: 
            $bread  = 'N1';       
        break;
    }  
}
```

How could I make `assertEquals` test with the local variable `$bread` in the unit test file? In the test file TestControllerTest I don't know how to access the local variable
`$bread`. How could I access local `$bread` in the unit test file?

[image]

Comment: Your function needs to return something if you want to test it like this. But to be more precise with an answer you should share your routing setup as well.

$bread is only available in the context of your function - not outside. If you want to assert the response of your api call, you must return the value of $bread.

Comment: That is my return code :

        return view('frontend.book')->with(compact('levels','bread'));

Answer (score 3):

A unit test should test the *functionality* of a piece of code, not its *implementation*: it specifies some *inputs* or *conditions*, and then tests some *outputs* or *effects*. Then if you *change* the implementation of the function, the unit test can tell you if you've accidentally changed the *functionality*.

As such, even if you *could* inspect local variables in the test, it would be a bad idea, because you'd be testing the specific implementation, not the functionality.

Your example function doesn't make any sense, because it doesn't actually have any outputs or effects: it sets a local variable, and then finishes without returning or storing it anywhere.

A more realistic function would be this:

```php
public function levels($id){
    switch($id){
        case 5: 
            $bread = 'N2';
        break;
        case 1: 
            $bread  = 'N1';       
        break;
    }
    return $bread;
}
```

Now, you can write tests like "if I pass $id as 5, I should get a return value of 'N2'":

```
public function test_example() {
    $output = levels(5);
    $this->assertSame('N2', $output);
}
```

You could even use a [Data Provider](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#data-providers) to write a whole list of input-output pairs.

Later, you might change the function to use a PHP 8 [match statement](https://www.php.net/match) and don't bother with the local variable at all. The unit tests will tell you if the new code still has the same *functionality* as the old code, or if you've introduced a bug.

```php
public function levels($id){
    return match($id){
        5 => 'N2',
        1 => 'N1',
    };
}
```

If the problem is that the real-life function is really long, and the part you want to test is buried in the middle somewhere, that's a good sign you need to do some *re-factoring*: break the code up into smaller functions, and then test each part.